# Open a local copy of Force.com project using MavensMate in ST3

Tags: mavensmate

I am already using Force.com plugin in eclipse but now want to open the same copy in MavensMate using Sublime text 3 IDE.

Provide some suggestions if its possible ??

Comment: do you mean open the same project ?

Answer (score 9):

MavensMate and Force.com plugin share the same directory structure, which enables you to use this [process](http://mavensmate.com/Plugins/Sublime_Text/Existing_Projects) to open the project in MavensMate.

> Connecting MavensMate to an existing Force.com (non-MavensMate) project

Comment: but when i am passing the workspace path till `*/src` folder then also i am not able to open files.
It always shows `Can't Find Project file for: classes`.

Comment: Are you dragging the parent folder containing your /src folder into MavensMate, the steps i link to shows this as MyCoolProject in the example.

Comment: This is not the correct path, as Eclipse worksapces contain the project folder, then the src folder. Try dragging the project subfolder in workspace folder.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is stored in a repo somewhere, you may try this procedure:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/164640/12151

> 1. Clone your repo inside your mm_workspace
> 2. Open sublimetext
> 3. Click File > Open Folder
> 4. In your sidebar (make sure your side bar is visible. toggle it using Ctrl+K,Ctrl+B), right click on the root folder, click MavensMate > Create MavensMate Project...
> 5. Your mavensmate app will open up. Just press the big blue button in the upper right that says "Create MavensMate Project".