# Create new app from existing code in git

Tags: mavensmate

I do have some salesforce code on a side to build a package and it's inside a git repo.

I would like to git clone that repo and deploy the package in a new dev instance in order to make some tests. I'm doing that with mavensmate.

I don't know how I can push to the org the ApexClass, Custom Objects and pages. I tried to "compile" the project but I got some errors, it looks like it requires to have the files on the server already, but this is what I'm tying to do.

I think I'm also facing some prerequisite stuff on Salesforce, should I create an "app" firsts ? I don't know.

I just clone some code, and I want to try that code on a new dev org with mavensmate, could you please advise ?

Answer (score 0):

I generally use Ant to deploy a new project cloned from git, but I'm fairly sure you can do it in MavensMate by either using "Deploy to Server" or possibly opening up all the downloaded classes/pages/objects and using "Compile all Tabs" (though that's quite a bit more tedious).

There is additional information here - [synching cloned github repo to org with mavensmate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22677/synching-cloned-github-repo-to-org-with-mavensmate)

Comment: That's weird but the deploy to server doesn't seems to send ALL the objects and classes I have in my source folder. but I my `package.xml` I have `<members>*</members><name>ApexClass</name>`

Comment: When using Deploy to Server in MM I'm fairly sure you have to manually select the components in the Metadata tab.