# Cloned Git Repostiory and MavensMate [Does not work]

Tags: mavensmate, git

There are similar questions. But, the answers do not work.
Please advise.

I followed these steps few times. However, was not able to create MavensMate Project.

Cloned repo on local(To MMWorkspace).

Opened sublimetext

Clicked File > Open Folder

Referred to this thread.
[synching cloned github repo to org with mavensmate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22677/synching-cloned-github-repo-to-org-with-mavensmate)

"Create MavensMate Project" is not available.

@SamuelDev, could you please advise?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The steps I follow to open a cloned repo in MM are as follows:

- Open a cmd prompt in my MavensMate project folder (the root folder)
- Clone the repository into this folder (feel free to rename as needed).
- In Sublime, select "Projects->Close Project" (be sure no project is open)
- Drag the new folder with the repository into Sublime
- Right-click on the  folder and select "MavensMate->Make Project"
- Be sure add the Sublime files to .gitignore (*.sublime-project, config/*)

One difference I've noted from your steps is that I'm cloning the repo into my MM project folder as opposed to adding the github folder to the MM configuration. I prefer to have all my MM projects under a single folder structure (C:\Salesforce.com\MavensMate\ in my case).

*Edited to add a screen capture*
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Force2b. However, as illustrated in above screenshot, MavensMate menu shows only one option.
i.e. MavensMate -> Delete files from Salesforce Server.

There is no Make Project.

Comment: Looking at your original screen capture, try dragging the root folder of the project - not the src folder - into Sublime. See the screen capture I just added to my answer above. That should resolve the issue.